# C++ Callback in a different class

Tags: c++

Here is my problem,
I have two classes, MainMenuState and MainMenuUI. MainMenuState has a MainMenuUI member.
Basically, I want to do all my GUI initialization in MainMenuUI

```
void GameUI::MainMenuUI::initUi()
{
    std::shared_ptr<GUI::Label> testLabel2(new GUI::Label);
    testLabel2->setFont(m_font);
    testLabel2->setText("TestLabel");
    testLabel2->setFontColor(sf::Color(0, 0, 0));
    testLabel2->setFontSize(16);
    testLabel2->setRelativePosition(GUI::Position::RIGHT, GUI::Position::BOTTOM, -5, -5);
    addComponent("label2", testLabel2);



    std::shared_ptr<GUI::MainMenuPanel> mainMenu(new GUI::MainMenuPanel(font));
    mainMenu->setRelativePosition(GUI::Position::MIDDLE, GUI::Position::MIDDLE);
    mainMenu->open();
// Problem !---------------
    /*mainMenu->setPlayButtonCallback([this]{
        requestStackPop(); // This method belongs to MainMenuState's base class and is protected
        requestStackPush(States::AnotherState); // This method belongs to MainMenuState's base class and is protected
    });
    mainMenu->setExitButtonCallback([this]{
        requestStackPop(); // This method belongs to MainMenuState's base class and is protected
    });*/
//--------------------
    addComponent("mainMenu", mainMenu);
}
```

As you can see, the problem is "How to set my callbacks directly in my MainMenuUI class ?". Could friend classes help me ?

Thank you

Comment: You may want to look at std::mem_fn and possibly std::bind or boost:bind.

Comment: @Joe: I don't see how either of those things will help. Indeed, a lambda is the cleanest approach. The problem here is one of access rights _inside_ the callback.

Comment: isn't it the point of all the public methods? create some public methods that you can access everywhere

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to expose those methods to the world you could create a class that can access those methods and provide such interface and pass instance of that class as a parameter to callback:

```
mainMenu->setPlayButtonCallback([this](Accessor acc){
        acc.requestStackPop(); 
        acc.requestStackPush(States::AnotherState); 
    });
```